# Combodate date-picker border issue for date of birth field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, combodate

I am using the combodate dropdown date picker for my application.The issue when i open it in the firefox browser the border is not coming .

Below images gives clear idea like what is happening.

[image]

Here the for the month field dropdown the border is not coming.

but coming date and year it is working fine.
[image]

I am not getting where it is going wrong.please help me out with this issue.

Many Thanks in advance....

Comment: this is actually due to an bug in ff https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=924068

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a bug in firefox [Reference](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=924068)

Ideally you could give width 99.99% instead of 100% in your css to your particular select drop down.

Comment: ,If i do that the UI alignment is getting disturbed,for particular select dropdown i am using style="width:auto;"

Comment: yes you need to add a unique class to the particular select dropdown first. Then you need to reduce the width on that particular class, so that other select dropdowns dont get effected.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around on this like in combodate.js we have a js line

```
this.$widget.find('select').css('width', 'auto').addClass('form-control');
```

and i Made it to

```
this.$widget.find('select').css('width', '92px').addClass('form-control');
```

This helped me out and working fine in all browsers and ipad/iphones.